# Question regarding carnot engine

Tags: thermodynamics, carnot-cycle

Why is it drawn as though the $heat$ is the entering & leaving  the parallelogram in $PV Diagram$ of $Carnot$ $Cycle$.

[image: PV Diagram of Carnot Cycle]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a dithermic engine, meaning that during a cycle, the fluid comes in contact with two constant-temperature systems:

- the "hot source" during $1\to 2$
- the "cold source" during $3\to 4$

Since it's an engine, it lets heat flow naturally from hot to cold, and extract work in the process. So the fluid *receives* heat from the hot source and *yields* heat to the cold source. This explains the direction of the arrows for heat flows $Q_1$ (from hot) and $Q_2$ (to cold).

Comment: So the direction indicated that the heat source is above the setup and the cold source is below the setup ?

Comment: No, the diagram gives no spatial information about the actual shape or constitution of the engine. It only gives temporal information (the order of the four transformations). During 1->2 the systems comes in contact with the hot source, during 3->4 with the cold one, nothing more.

Comment: Oh ,I see,so when the arrow crosses the path 1$\implies $2,it is supposed to signify  $Q_1$ amount of heat is added to the system and for the path 3$\implies$4 ,it signifies $Q_2$ amount of heat leaves the system ?

Comment: Yes, that's it. :)